# Rails not serving because of sqlite gem version mismatch on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Im on a windows machine and i have rails installed.
Im trying to serve my app but i keep getting this error instead of the welcome page:

```
Puma caught this error: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.4), already activated sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

Im using version 1.3.13 of the sqlite3 gem because ive read that the newest version of the gem is incompatible with rails(atleast on windows). How can i correct this

Comment: Use Postgres, MySQL or whatever you're actually planning to use in production. The only reason Rails defaults to SQLite is convenience which definely doesn't seem to apply if you're torturing yourself by developing on windows.

Comment: Right thanks, trying to get the mysql driver of ruby now